# "SELECT .. WHERE .. AND .." (two conditions) for a key-value table?

Tags: mysql, key-value

## What I'm Trying To Do

**I am trying to get the `commentId` by asking `type = x` and `target = x`**,

**normally (THIS IS A EXAMPLE)**, the structure of the table should looks like this:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+
| commentId | type  | target |
+-----------+-------+--------+
|         1 | post  |      2 |
|         2 | post  |      8 |
|         3 | video |      6 |
+-----------+-------+--------+
```

and in this situation, I can use this query to get the `commentId`:

```
SELECT `commentId` FROM `comment_datas` WHERE type = 'post' AND target = '2'
```

---

## Real Problem

But **this is the real structure of the table** (with the key-value design):

```
+-----------+--------+-------+
| commentId |  name  | value |
+-----------+--------+-------+
|         1 | type   | post  |
|         1 | target | 2     |
|         2 | type   | post  |
|         2 | target | 8     |
|         3 | type   | post  |
|         3 | target | 6     |
+-----------+--------+-------+
```

now I don't know how to get the `commentId` by the query which I wrote above, any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a MySQL query for selecting from a table storing key value pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287822/need-a-mysql-query-for-selecting-from-a-table-storing-key-value-pairs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until @juergen-d fixes his typo: here is the corrected version:

```
SELECT commentId 
FROM comment_datas  
GROUP BY commentId
HAVING sum(name = 'type' AND value = 'post') > 0 
   AND sum(name = 'target' AND value = '2') > 0
```

**Explanation:**

`sum` accepts a aggregate expression besides column names so the idea is to sum the entries with `name = type` and `value = post`
By having the `sum` to be greater than 0 the select returns only the rows of the `group by` that satisfy the aggregate expression - same goes for `target`.

Answer (score 5):

Group by the `commentId`. Then you can filter those groups having at least one record with the conditons you want

```
SELECT commentId 
FROM comment_datas 
GROUP BY commentId
HAVING sum(name = 'type' and value = 'post') > 0 
   AND sum(name = 'target' and value = '2') > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but an error occurred: `Unknown column 'type' in 'having clause'`, the second table is my real structure, does my question mislead you :)?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a select over the value number with a subselect over the type or the other way around.

Something like

```
SELECT commentId FROM comment_datas
WHERE name="type" AND value="post"
AND commentId IN (
    SELECT commentId FROM comment_datas WHERE name="target" AND value=2
);
```

---

But seriously, you will run into such problems more often if you leave the schema like that. You're basically having two rows instead of one.

Instead of "name" and "value" better use the actual names and values as column names and values. So remove "name" and "value", and add "type" and "target" as columns. This way you'll have no double entries and you can make the ID unique. Your current schema puts a key-value system on top of a key-value system.

Comment: I have different datas based on different types, I might add `type` and `target` as the columns since both are the required datas and does `WHERE type="post"` a typo?

Comment: I'm really appreciated for your advice :).

Answer (score 0):

user this, you will get two records

```
SELECT `commentId` FROM `comment_datas ` WHERE (name = 'type' AND value = 'post') OR (name = 'target' AND value = '2') GROUP BY `commentId`
```

Comment: It selected all the rows and gave me a `commentId` list.

Comment: This selects all posts AND a line with target=2 of any type.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    SELECT 
            `commentId` 
    FROM 
            `comment_datas` 
    WHERE 
            (`name` = 'type'   AND `value` = 'post') OR 
            (`name` = 'target' AND `value` = '2') 
    GROUP BY
            `commentId`
```

Comment: this will select all posts and the one entry with value=2 no matter what type it is.